# Ubuntu 12.04LTS and blu-ray

Tags: 12.04, vlc, blu-ray

I have a blu-ray disc (original),ubuntu 12.04LTS and VLC 2.0.10. I have followed this guide on web but VLC still not working:

```
    sudo apt-get install libbluray-bdj libaacs0
mkdir ~/.config/aacs/
cd ~/.config/aacs/ && wget http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/files/KEYDB.cfg
```

In particular I have these errors:

```
Your system AACS decoding library does not work. Missing keys?
```

and

```
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'bluray:///media/86305423_PRESTIGE'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by [OP](https://askubuntu.com/users/423264/linofex) with [edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/662112/2):

> I have solved! I think that some months ago I already tried that guide and in that aacs folder I had got 5 key files. So I have deleted all and follow the guide again. Now all is working!